# Explanation of (doc ->) clojure

Tags: clojure

If you run `(doc ->)`, it says:

```
clojure.core/->
([x] [x form] [x form & more])
Macro
  Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  second item in second form, etc.
```

What I don't understand why it says `second item in the first form`, what it is the `first item` in that context?

Even if you run `(source ->)`:

```
(source ->)
(defmacro ->
   "Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
    second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
    list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
    second item in second form, etc."
    {:added "1.0"}
    ([x] x)
    ([x form] (if (seq? form)
          (with-meta `(~(first form) ~x ~@(next form)) (meta form))
          (list form x)))
     ([x form & more] `(-> (-> ~x ~form) ~@more)))
```

`x` is passed as 1st argument to `form`, so what do I miss here, why the documentation call `x` the `second item`.

Answer (score 1):

Each function is called with the result of the previous functions passed as the second thing in the list. it will be put just after the function name:

```
(third-function 
  (second-function 
    (first-function :initial-value :second-arg-to-first-function) 
    :second-arg-to-second-function) 
  :second-arg-to-third-function)
```

would translate to this if we used the threading macro instead, (and label the list positions):

```
 (-> :initial-value
     (first-function      :second-arg-to-first-function) 
     ;;    1          2               3          

     (second-function     :second-arg-to-second-function)
     ;;    1          2               3 

     (third-function      :second-arg-to-third-function))
     ;;    1          2               3
```

The value of the previous function get put by in positions 2 by this macro.

There is a very similar macro `as->` (pronounced "thread-as") which gives the threaded value an explicit name and helps make the transformation more clear:

```
user> (as-> 4 x ;; x starts as 4
        (+ x 4) ;; and it's value in each call is the result of the previous
        (- x 2 1) 
        (* x x 2))
50
```

Answer (score 0):

The second item of the form *is* the first argument to the function.

This is a form which is a list

```
(println "world")
```

The evaluation semantic is to make a function call with the *first item of the list being the function* and the rest being the arguments.

Macro's don't evaluate their arguments though. We can suppress evaluation ourselves by quoting to see what's going on.

```
(def foo '(println "world"))

(first foo) ;=> foo
(second foo) ;=> "world"
```

If we insert "hello" as the second item in this form

```
(def bar `(~(first foo) "hello" ~@(rest foo)))
bar ;=> (clojure.core/println "hello" "world")

(-> "hello" (println "world"))
;=>hello world
```